# checking post on page

Tags: asp.net

I have the page and several buttons on it. One of them should post the data on this page, another one has event that also reload page but doesn't post data. The question: how can I check in event Page Load was the data posted or not?

Comment: Can you show a part of your code?

Comment: Could you show us some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to check what control caused the post back

```
string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
{
    return this.Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
}
```

http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
if (IsPostBack) { ... }
```

Comment: I use it now, it is not ok "Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback." (msdn). It is not about posting data. Actualy when event apearce of button that doesn't post any data I have the error.